# Вывод нескольких записей из таблицы MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Доброго времени всем

У меня есть таблица и я хочу на страницу вывести сразу несколько записей а не одну, что мне для этого нужно сделать?

Буду рад примеру или ссылки, в любом случае спасибо

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 15`

вывести все колонки из таблицы **table** для первых пятнадцати записей

`SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 15`

вывести все колонки из таблицы **table** для пятнадцати записей, пропустив пять первых (т.е. с шестой по двадцатую)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    /* Подключение к серверу MySQL */ 
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',  'root',   '1234','database');

/* Хост, к которому мы подключаемся */ 
 /* Имя пользователя */ 
/* Используемый пароль */   /* База данных для запросов по умолчанию */

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
   printf("Подключение к серверу MySQL невозможно. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
   exit; 
}

/* Посылаем запрос серверу */

if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, tema FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5')) {

    print("Список статей:<br> \n");

    /* Выбираем результаты запроса: */

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $row['id'], $row['tema']);

    }

/* определение числа рядов в выборке */

    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("В выборке %d рядов.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* Освобождаем память */

    $result->close(); 
}

/* Закрываем соединение */

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: это  минимум для получения запроса из базы данных MySQL, при помощи библиотеки mysqli.